# Not seeing any of my website code in the repo - ghpages react

Tags: github-pages

A while ago I created my github pages website with react app. I can still access it fine when I go to the url - it shows it up to date with whatever styling or things I added. but when I clone the repo to my computer and try see what files/code there is, I'm not seeing any of the typescript code related to the website. There are a few commits but they were from when I first created the app. Like there is the App.tsx file but in that is just the bare bones of whats usually given when you create the react app

As it's been a while since I made it I'm not sure if I have forgotten to do something. Is it something to do with the two branches, master and gh-pages?

Comment: be sure of all branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the TypeScript files are stored in a different branch than the one you are currently cloning. When you clone a repository, you only clone the current branch by default.

What you can do is:

1. `git clone --recursive <repository URL>` to clone all the branches
2. Use `git branch` to list all the branches.
3. Switch branch using the `git checkout` command.
4. Lookup and the file should in one of the branch.

Comment: When I check git branches after cloning like you said it only shows the master branch, it doesn't even show the gh-pages branch which shows up on github

Comment: That should work with `git clone --recursive <repository URL>` but if it is not working then checkout specific branch with `git clone -b gh-pages git_repository_url`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git branch -r` to show all remote branches, then when you see the desired branch "origin/branch_name", run `git checkout branch_name` without the origin prefix to check it out and do a pull.  It should be set up to track it automatically.

You could also run `git branch -t branch_name origin/branch_name` and check it out for the same result.

gh-pages used to be the publishing source branch used by all GitHub pages websites ([source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site)), it's possible that your code is there.